# React: Understanding import statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the difference between these two statements

```
import React from 'react';
```

and

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Shouldn't **import React from 'react'** import everything including the content? What should I read to understand this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Importing something **without curly braces** imports whatever was defined as the `default export` in the module from which you are importing. There can only be exactly one (or no) default export in a module.

**foo.js**:

```
const myObject = {foo: 'bar'};
export default myObject;
```

**bar.js**:

```
import theObject from './foo';

console.log(theObject);
// prints {foo: 'bar'}
// note that default exports are not named and can be imported with another name
```

Importing **with curly braces** imports what was exported as a named export with that name by the module. There can be multiple named exports in a module.

**foo.js**:

```
export const myObject = {foo: 'bar'};
export const anotherObject = {bar: 'baz'};
```

**bar.js**:

```
import {myObject, anotherObject, theObject} from './foo';

console.log(myObject);
// prints {foo: 'bar'}

console.log(anotherObject);
// prints {bar: 'baz'}

console.log(theObject);
// prints undefined
// because nothing named "theObject" was exported from foo.js
```

Answer (score 4):

With

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

you can do

```
class Menu extends Component { /* ... */ }
```

instead of

```
class Menu extends React.Component { /* ... */ }
```

from this: [Import React vs React, { Component }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361282/import-react-vs-react-component#39361329)

Comment: also, check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361282/import-react-vs-react-component#39361329

Comment: Can you please include that link in answer (update/edit the answer) and then I will mark it as answered.

Comment: That's not correct - the first one *does* import the `Component` property (along with everything else in React), it just gives you the destructured `Component` as a standalone variable to reference as well.

Comment: Regarding that link - one other advantage of using `extends Component` instead of `extends React.Component` is that it would be easier to refactor your code if you decided for some reason in the future to have all components in your app extend from a custom component class. But that's probably very unlikely for most apps.

Comment: my apologies, you are right. I will correct for sake of not misleading anyone

Answer (score 2):

This is the ES6.

```
import Raect, { Component } from 'react';
```

Like

```
import default_export, { named_export } from 'react';
```

Consider two file. Person.js like

```
const person = {
  name: 'johon doe'
}
export default person; // default export
```

Utility.js like

```
export const clean = () => { ... } //named export using const keyword
export const baseData = 10; //named export using const keyword
```

inport in App.js file. like

```
import person from './Person';
import prs from './Person';

import {clean} from './Utility';
import {baseData} from './Utility';

import {data as baseData} from './Utility';
import {* as bundled} from './Utility';
//bundled.baseData
//bundled.clean
```

Answer (score 1):

João Belo posted a great answer to read, but I'll add one more thing. the second instance is using destructuring and object-shorthand to grab the 'Component' property's value from the react module and assign it to a 'Component' variable that you can use locally. If you don't know about destructuring and object-shorthand, you should definitely look them up. They come in handy.

Comment: Technically import statements aren't quite the same as object destructuring. It's the same concept and the syntax is very similar, but there are some syntactic differences, e.g. `import { Foo as AliasToFoo }` vs. `const { Foo: AliasToFoo } = ...`

Comment: Very true. Thanks for elaborating.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, this boils down to the way you export variables. I believe, this must be a deliberate design decision from Facebook contributors.

```js
export default class ReactExample {}

export class ComponentExample {}
export class ComponentExampleTwo {}
```

in the above example, ReactExample can be imported without using {}, where as the ComponentExample, ComponentExampleTwo , you have to import using {} statements.

The best way to understand is going through the source code.

[React export source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/index.js)

[React Component source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js)

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as myCode from './../../myCode';
```

This inserts myCode into the current scope, containing **all the exports** from the module in the file located in `./../../myCode`.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class myComponent extends Component { ... }
```

By Using above syntax your bundler ( e.g : webpack) will still bundle the ENTIRE dependency but since the `Component` module is imported in such a way using `{ }` into the namespace, we can just reference it with `Component`instead of `React.Component`.

For more information you can read [mozilla ES6 module docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).