# import * as React from "react" -- Will importing everything impact performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import, single-page-application

As I understand it, the following code will import everything which is marked as export in `react`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

whereas

```
import { Component } from 'react'
```

will only import the Component. Are there technical reasons why one shouldn't just

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

everywhere in their code?

Comment: I guess it should. Not sure about react's package size, but for lodash it is said that one should import only relevant functions because of its huge size.

Comment: You can also import React and use the others without importing it. then use React.useEffect.. Reach.useState...etc. for hooks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import React vs React, { Component }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361282/import-react-vs-react-component)